# Linq sum of percentage of yearly sales of the Others category exceed 100%

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query that calculates the sum of sales by year and country. Everything works fine except when a put those countries with less than 2% of total sales into the "Others" category

My code:

```
using (var context = new ChinookContext())
{
  var rawset = context.Invoices.Include(l => l.InvoiceLines)
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.BillingCountry, i.InvoiceDate.Year })
    .Select(f => new
    {
      Country = f.Key.BillingCountry,
      Year = f.Key.Year,
      TotalSales = f.Sum(l => l.InvoiceLines.Sum(t => t.Quantity * t.UnitPrice))
    })
    .ToList();

  var result = rawset
    .Select(r => new {
    GrandTotal = rawset.Sum(t => t.TotalSales),
    CountryTotal =
      rawset.GroupBy(c => c.Country)
      .Select(p => new
      {
        CountryKey = p.Key,
        CountryTotalSales = p.Sum(t => t.TotalSales)
      }),
      Member = r})
      .Select(f => new
      {
        Country = (
          f.CountryTotal
          .Where(c => c.CountryKey == f.Member.Country)
          .Select(x => x.CountryTotalSales).SingleOrDefault()
          / f.GrandTotal > 0.02M)
          ? f.Member.Country : "Others",
          Year = f.Member.Year,
          YearlySales = f.Member.TotalSales,
          TotalSalesByCountry = f.CountryTotal
            .Where(c => c.CountryKey == f.Member.Country)
            .Select(c => c.CountryTotalSales).FirstOrDefault(),
          GrandTotal = f.GrandTotal
      })
      .ToList();

  var finalresult = result.GroupBy(r => new { r.Country, r.Year })
    .Select(final => new
    {
      Country = final.Key.Country,
      Year = final.Key.Year,
      YearlySales = final.Sum(y => y.YearlySales),
      PercentageByCountry = final.Sum(y => y.YearlySales)
        / final.Sum(c => c.TotalSalesByCountry)
        * 100,
      PercentageByGrandTotal = final.Sum(y => y.YearlySales)
        / final.Select(x => x.GrandTotal).FirstOrDefault()
        * 100
  })
  .OrderBy(f => f.Country)
  .ThenBy(f => f.Year);
}
```

The problem is the percentage of yearly sale for each country for the total sales for that country.

All other countries worked well except for the "Others" category which exceeds 100%.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While calculating `TotalSalesByCountry` you are not considering "Others" case, ie when its less than 2%. So the calculation will go wrong when you do `PercentageByCountry = final.Sum(y => y.YearlySales)
        / final.Sum(c => c.TotalSalesByCountry)
        * 100` in the case of "Others" country.

Comment: Thanks! I will now correct that

Comment: On a secong look, I think I was wrong.

Comment: I have added `TotalByCountry = final.Sum(c => c.TotalSalesByCountry)` to the last query and the result for "Others" is different for each year. Other countries all have the same value

Comment: Fair amount of discrepancy, in the way you have calculated `YearlySales` and `TotalSalesByCountry`, which happens due to the structure created in the calculation, `var result = rawset.Select`, since even though you are having CountryTotal, which is grouped for country, but number of records will remain same as `rawset` due to following entry `Member = r`, ensure everything is grouped by the `Country`, instead of repeated data, which is creating an issue down the line, in the calculation of `YearlySales` and `TotalSalesByCountry`. Aldo if possible post some data for me try some solution.

Comment: @Developer, actually you were right. The `TotalSalesByCountry` calculates the sum of each country that make up the "Others" group. I managed to solve it by adding another sum to the countries that make up the "Others" group. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calculating `TotalSalesByCountry` you are not considering "Others" case, ie when its less than 2%. So the calculation will go wrong when you do `PercentageByCountry = final.Sum(y => y.YearlySales) / final.Sum(c => c.TotalSalesByCountry) * 100` in the case of "Others" country